# Content vote system with IP verification and dynamic IP adresses

Tags: web-development, ip-address

#### Description:

I have two types of vote system on my site.

First of them is for all users and store IP adress to prevent more than one vote. Second is for authenticated users only, which also store nickname.

#### Problem to solve:

Dynamic IP adress will change in about 24 hours with second type of vote system it doesn't really matter because of stored nickname but in first case IP is the only data about user action.

There is chance that User 1 which had IP `X` yesterday have now adress `Y` and cannot vote today because User 2 had `Y` IP a day before and already "locked" row in database. According to this User 1 cannot vote on content despite of he/she should been able to do it.

#### Question:

Should I delete all IP adresses in first and/or second case of vote system due to dynamic IP technology (at least once per 24h)?

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe not 100% flawless, but I would combine an IP & cookie check system.

First check for the IP in a database or log, if exists, check if a cookie is set/created. If IP exists but cookie doesn't, then voting is allowed. If cookie exists with another IP, then no voting is allowed because cookie is only set/created after a vote.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot approve this anserw. Just tell me do you agree with my logic in subject of dynamic IP? I have on single page 10 vote instances and those pages will go in hundreds so it won't be effective in the long term. Also cookie system as it is client side verification is like "Pls dont vote again".. I can easily spoof that system.

Comment: It has nothing to do whith your logic but imho it is far from flawless. IP spoofing is easier than you think (using vpn's/proxies and so on). I won't start a discussion here, ask the payed system's how they do and you have my answer.

Comment: IP Spoofing with VPS need at least basic knowledge about how IP works. Typicall user don't know how to manipulate his/her IP adress but know how to delete cookies from browser - that was my point. According to this and many vote rows system it won't help me with my problem. Maybe I wrote my comment before too unclearly, btw look on my "Question" paragraph and your anserw on this, I didn't ask what should I do to make vote system more reliable (which your anserw is about). Now look on my first sentence from my first comment. I really cannot use your option of vote implementation.